# RIP Cliff Simon (Stargate SG1 Ba'al)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Cliff Simon was best known in sci-fi circles as [the Goa'uld System Lord Ba'al in Stargate SG1](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Ba%27al). He [died in a kiteboarding accident](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-56371582)

> "He was known to most of you on this page as the villain you loved to hate, Ba'al, from Stargate SG-1," Colette Simon said in a post on Facebook.

Later

> But he secured the biggest role of his career after moving to Los Angeles. His portrayal of villain Ba'al on Stargate SG1 was popular with viewers and the character enjoyed a five-year run.